# Ambiguities while converting List<Object[]> to List<Integer>

Tags: java, list, data-conversion

We were trying to fetch results from database via `SQL` query using `hibernate` which will return `List<Object[]>`, if records are present. But later we want to convert it into a `List<Integer>`. So instead of iterating through the `Object[]` list and keep on adding to integer list, we tried something and the sample code is like

```
public class ListObjectArrayToListInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] ob1 = {1};
        Object[] ob2 = {5};
        Object[] ob3 = {9};
        List objList = new ArrayList();
        objList.add(ob1);
        objList.add(ob2);
        objList.add(ob3);

        //Case - 1
        List<Integer> intList = objList;
        System.out.println(intList);

        //Case - 2          
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        intList.addAll(objList);
        System.out.println(intList);
    }
}
```

We are only trying to fetch one column from the query and that's why all the `Arrays` are having only one element. Both **Case-1** and **Case-2** were executed separately and output was same in both case, it was something like this

> [[Ljava.lang.Object;@3e25a5, [Ljava.lang.Object;@19821f,
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;@addbf1]

In **Case-1** `intList` a type of `List<Integer>`, is pointing to an object of `List` with `Object[]`s. We were expecting an Exception in run time because the data types are entirely different.

In **Case-2** we are explicitly adding `Object[]`s to `List<Integer>` and without any exception it is giving an output which up to my knowledge is wiered.

1. So can anybody explain why we are getting output like this?
2. How a `List<Integer>`, which is expecting only `Integers` at all its locations, would hold a data like this `[[Ljava.lang.Object;@3e25a5, [Ljava.lang.Object;@19821f]`?
3. Why would Java allow users to add data from a raw data list to a generic list. In my code if I make `Object[] ob1 = {1, 2, "3", "abc"};` it can be added to `intList` as `intList.addAll(objList);` which is allowed and runs smoothly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: Wombat was a bit trigger-happy, but your question is really a duplicate, see what @JBNizet has linked.

Comment: @tevemadar the link from JBNizet was helpful in clarifying my concerns about the Exceptions, but what about my second question?

Comment: Well you used a raw type, thus allowing any type of object to be added to the list. You added object arrays to that list. So, when printing it, it prints each object array. And the toString() method of arrays returns the type of the array (`[L` here) followed by its hashCode (`3e25a5`).

Comment: but @JB Nizet objList is my raw type list, I'm trying to print intList which is Integer type

Comment: Generic objects such as `ArrayList` don't/can't perform type checking on their elements at run-time. Generics only protect against compile-time errors. By using a raw type, you bypass the compile-time checks. That's why we don't use raw types. Also see e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html and https://stackoverflow.com/q/339699/2891664. You might also look at the code for [`ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#134) and note that it uses an `Object[]` array internally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Arun Sudhakaran, The three questions you asked can be answered like this:

**Question 1:**

**Case 1:**

You said: **"**`intList` a type of `List<Integer>`, is pointing to an object of `List` with `Object[]`s **"**.

This is incorrect because you are not initializing `objList` with the parameter `<Object[]>`; you are initializing `objList` like this: **List objList = new ArrayList();**.

By doing so, `objList` will be created as a `List` with **raw-type**, not as a `List` with type `Object[]`.

(more on **raw-type:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

Since `intList` is a type of `List<Integer>`, this means that `intList` is pointing to an object of `List` with **raw-type**- not to an object of `List` with type `Object[]`s.

Generics have been a part of Java since **JDK 1.5**. To maintain backward compatibility, Java has not removed collection initialization with **raw-type**.

```
//Case - 1
List<Integer> intList = objList;
```

In this case, `objList` is initialized with **raw-type**. By pointing `intList` to `objList`, the compiler does not know the type of value the `objList` collection variable is holding. This is why the compiler allows you to add an array of `Object` into `objList`.

**Case 2:**

```
//Case - 2          
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intList.addAll(objList);
System.out.println(intList);
```

You said: **"** we are explicitly adding `Object[]`s to `List<Integer>` and without any exception it is giving an output **"**

Again, This is incorrect. You are adding a `List` of type `Object[]` into `List<Integer>`- not `Object[]`s into `List<Integer>`. You are not doing `intList.add(ob1); intList.add(ob2);`. If you did this, then you could say that we are adding `Object[]`s into `List<Integer>`.

From **JDK 1.5** and onward, you can use generics to initialize collection variables like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); //or
List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

After that, when trying to add elements into `list`, the compiler will check whether or not the element has the same datatype as `list` or same sub-type of `list`. When you hover over a collection variable in IDEs like eclipse or intelliJ, you may see something like `List<? extends Integer>`.

But here, `objList` is initialized with **raw-type** not a generic type. This means the compiler does not know that `objList` is not of type `Integer` or of sub-type `Integer`. If this is the case, the compiler will not throw an exception. Instead, the compiler will traverse the list and give the reference values of `ob1`, `ob2` and `ob3.

**Question 2:**

When trying to add all elements of `objList` into `List<Integer>`, at compile time, the compiler will not know the data-type of `objList` because `objList` is of **raw-type**. As a result, the compiler will not throw an exception. Instead, the compiler will allow the user to add such element into `List<Integer>`. When trying to iterate through `List<Integer>`, you will find the reference value of the elements in `objList` which are `ob1`, `ob2` and `ob3`.

**Question 3:**

Java only allows users to add data from a raw data list to the generic list. This is done to support **compatibility** and is the reason that your code will run smoothly in both **JDK 1.4** and **JDK 1.8** without changing any code.

Answer (score 3):

In hibernate every Object in the array stands for a selected entity (table).

Best would be to have a query restricted to the required result:

```
  String hql = "select count(me.grp) from  MyEntity me group by grp";
  TypedQuery<Integer> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Integer.class);
  List<Integer> result = query.getResult();
```

Assuming you need the extended data for other purposes too:

```
  List<Integer> result = objList.stream()
          .map(oarr -> oarr[0])
          .map(Integer.class::cast)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

For a hibernate query `select A a, B b, C c` with not an int, but a class A:

```
List<Object[]> objList = ...

List<Integer> result = objList.stream()
          .map(oarr -> oarr[0])           // Object[] to Object
          .map(A.class::cast)             // Object to A
          .map(A::getId)                  // A to int A.getId()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

***On the code***

If objList would be typed, it would not compile.

```
    List<Object[]> objList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Without type parameters, the entire generic typing does not take hold for `objList`, and hence even for `intList`. With type erasure `intList` is just a List of Object, and all works.

Comment: its not the hibernate part that worries me. What I'm wondering is how that conversion is possible and why would it be allowed. How would a location which is expecting int type will be holding data of hexadecimal type.

Comment: Now I understand; this is a question on generic types, rather than hibernate queries. Added the explanation.